# Oracle Apex: Create a progress bar when waiting result

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I create a procedure to process data. This procedure take ~1 minute to complete. How can I create a wating (progress) bar to wait for the result of procedure?

Note: Now I use version 4 of Apex. Please help me the way to implement using javascript and css

Comment: you want Progressbar while page is loading or on submit?

Comment: @NikhilButani: The progress bar is shown after submiting and waiting for result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the easiest solution with no javascript or css.

Lets say you have a button named '**P1_Submit**' which submits the page and triggers you process. Edit the button and at **Action** select **Defined by Dynamic Action**. Then create a dynamic action with:

1. Event=Click
2. Selection Type=Button
3. Button=P1_Submit
4. Condition=No Condition
5. True Action=Submit Page
6. **Uncheck** Fire On Page Load
7. Show Processing=Yes

Comment: I found it and apply success. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few dynamic action based plug-ins that can be used for progress bars in APEX. Here is one I wrote.

https://github.com/drumbeg/apex-nprogress

[image]