# Apex 5.0: Show a progress bar while Database Action is performed

Tags: sql, oracle, progress-bar, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

**Implementing a Waitbar or Progressbar**

In my Apex 5.0 application I have a SQL Update which is taking very long to process, and I want to implement an indicator to show that it is still running, so that the user won't start the action again.

A progressbar would do the trick, can anyone suggest a way of doing so?

(plugins aren't possible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Apex: Create a progress bar when waiting result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716566/oracle-apex-create-a-progress-bar-when-waiting-result)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just  Change the action of your SUBMIT button to Dyanamic Action

- > On dynamic action choose **ON CLICK** as **Event** .Choose **Button** for **Selection Type** and Choose Name of your submit Button to **Button**
- > Then on **Action**, Choose **SUBMIT PAGE**
- > Then on **Request /Button Name**, put your SUBMIT button's Name.
- > Then set **SHOW PROCESSING** to YES

Answer (score 3):

Use the JavaScript function apex.sumbit to submit the page and include the showWait option to display the progress bar. Here is an example...

```
apex.submit({  request:"DELETE",  set:{"P1_DEPTNO":10, "P1_EMPNO":5433},  showWait:true});
```