# How do you prevent the ability to click after submitting the page in oracle apex 5.0?

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am using oracle apex 5.0 with theme: Universal Theme - 42. I am currently clicking on a SEARCH Button in order to submit the page. I call the following function:

```
javascript:apex.submit({request:'SEARCH',showWait:true});
```

This function call above creates the spinning symbol in the middle of the page, but the user still has the ability to click another button or even the same button. I was reading this post http://rimblas.com/blog/2015/08/enhancement-to-waitpopup-on-apex5/ which says use this function call: `apex.widget.waitPopup();`.

I used this as well, and I am have the same issue as when I use the first submit function. I looked at an example apex application where the functionality was working, and there is a div overlay element which appears in order to block the page.

Does anyone know if I need to change the theme/add a plug in/ or do anything else in order to get the div element to appear with the wait icon after submission? Any ideas or thoughts are helpful, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156333/apex-5-0-show-a-progress-bar-while-database-action-is-performed/36167728#36167728

Comment: I will use the dynamic action if needed, thanks. But do you know of any reason the showWait:true is not functioning correctly?

Comment: I included the dynamic action, and I am still experiencing the same problem, the user can still click on the page while the submit is processing

Comment: did you set `show processing` to yes?if you did, then there is no way that you can click any button or item in your page.when you submit, your page should look like a disabled page with a processing bar.

Comment: I did set show processing to yes, but I am still getting the same problem specified above. I get the processing bar(circle) but the page is not disabled. I guess I have to research this more since I agree with you but the functionality I expect is not happening.

Comment: sorry, im confused.did it display a processing bar or a processing circle?if you get the circle one, it means that you havent removed you js code that uses apex.submit?and the dynamic action is being overwritten by that js code.can you make an example in apex.oracle.com?

Comment: I am seeing the processing circle, but this was what I was getting with both the url and dynamic action[I removed url when I tried this]. Anyways, I got a solution from Rimblas over in oracle apex forum, which was to add css code to the page inline css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the thread that helped me get the correct answer: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3925427?sr=inbox&ru=252540.

The solution was to add css to the inline css of the page. Now both the url and dynamic action perform the expected way.

```
.apex_wait_overlay {
display: block;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #000;
z-index: 1001;
-moz-opacity: .5;
opacity: .5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better answer is this:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4167853?start=15&tstart=0

Simply add the `Page Submit` **TRUE** Action to your Dynamic Action and set the `Show Processing` to **Yes**.

Then you don't even need any **Enable** or **Disable** Actions on your button.