# ORACLE APEX 5.1 Error after process runs a long time

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am having an issue on a page which has a process that unfortunately runs a long time (4-5 mins). After the process I have a redirection to another page. What is interesting is that process actually finishes successfully ( but the sucess message doesn't show because of error) and the data is inserted etc. But the page does not redirect  and I am getting this error on screen.

(http://prntscr.com/p79sfq)

There is no error message. When I inspect the page there is this: http://prntscr.com/p79u4g

http://prntscr.com/p79u4g

http://prntscr.com/p79uhh

The debug log does not show anything out of the ordinary:

http://prntscr.com/p79w48

Is the process or something timing out? Is there any setting or any way this could be prevented from happening.

Comment: You could run that process in the background using dbms_scheduler. Then create a page that monitors the job progress and display that as output to the user. 
If you let the process run as part of a page process then it is likely the user thinks it is broken and closes the browser or tries to reload. Your apex page wlll also timeout based on your ORDS configuration.

Comment: I am already doing that with some procedures that need to run after the initial data delete/insert. I can't run the delete/insert part as a job because it is dependent on a apex collection (which in production is very large, and why it is taking a long time). Like I stated in my question, the user is not closing the browser but is getting the error message...after which the page does not redirect (debug log shows that everything was completed). I will need to look into ORDS configuration.

Comment: An apex collection is just a table, so you could move the data into another table with a session id and then process it as a job. If you want to pursue the waiting on the screen option - how are you doing the submit. Is this a normal submit ? If so you could use one of the solutions described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156333/apex-5-0-show-a-progress-bar-while-database-action-is-performed

Comment: Yes...that is an option...The submit is a regular submit. The waiting is not the problem (The rotating arrow indicator shows up) and that is not what my question is about. My question is about the error that shows up (even though the debug log shows everything finished successfully) and the fact that because of that error the page does not redirect.

Comment: Could be a bug. I tried reproducing on 19.1: 
Created blank page with button that submits page, page process 
 ```begin
dbms_session.sleep(500);
end;```. Unconditional branch to page 2. When I run the page and click the button I see the spinner and it branches to 2 as expected when finished. Try replacing your process with the dbms_session.sleep to see if that makes a difference.